# Scala: Convert if to case

Tags: scala

I have following code segment I am still learning Scala and haven't really use case within-case: but I want to convert the if statement that I have to more scala way of doing things:

```
... 
.flatMap { 
case(title, subtitle, c, d, e, f, g, h) =>
  val tiitleSubTitle = (title + " " + subtitle).split("\\s").toSet.toList
  tiitleSubTitle.map(term => (
    if (a contains term)
    {
      Some(query, term, List(item_id).mkString(","))
    } else {
        None
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without a description of what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps you want something like:

```
Seq(title, subtitle)
  .flatMap(_ split "\\s")
  .filter(a contains _)
  .map((query, _, item_id)
```

To answer your question, directly, though: You could replace

```
{ term => 
  if (a contains term) Some(query, term, item_id)
  else None
}
```

with

```
{
  case term if a contains term => Some(query, term, item_id)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: actually before flatmap i am using a TypePipe from twitter api problem  i had using if was that i can't do any map or group later due to else not return a proper type. I think I like your first solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the if statement

```
if (a contains term)
{
    Some(query, term, List(item_id).mkString(","))
} else {
    None
}
```

with:

```
a contains term match {
    case true => Some(query, term, List(item_id).mkString(","))
    case false => None
}
```